# Network Windows computer won't show in Finder of Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: windows, osx-snow-leopard, networking, finder

Old Macs had windows locations automatically shown in the [Finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29) under Network. New Macs doesn't. How come and how can I change it?

Comment: Does the reply by @th3dude answer your question, or do you specifically want those machines to appear in the Finder?

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect to the Windows computer from your Mac manually.

> 1. In the Finder, choose Go > “Connect to Server.”
> 2. Type the network address for the computer in the Server Address field
>      using one of these formats:
>
>    smb://DNSname/sharename
>
>    smb://IPaddress/sharename
> 3. Follow the onscreen instructions to type the workgroup name and a user
>      name and password, and choose the
>      shared folder you want to access.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8849.html

After you do that, you can set up the connection to happen automatically when you login to your Mac from the Accounts settings window.